# When to use TextFrame or TextFrame2 in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

Example, in Powerpoint:

[The TextFrame object:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb265592%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

> Represents the text frame in a Shape object. Contains the text in the
>   text frame and the properties and methods that control the alignment
>   and anchoring of the text frame.

[The TextFrame2 object:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb265972%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

> Represents the text frame in a Shape or ShapeRange object. Contains
>   the text in the text frame and exposes properties and methods that
>   control the alignment and anchoring of the text frame.

So TextFrame2 also refers to `ShapeRange` object, and it has a few more properties than TextFrame.

I am not really sure when or whether I should use one or the other, for example, to manipulate the text values held in Table cells on a powerpoint slide.  Both seem to work, and the following statement returns `TRUE`.

```
Dim tbl as Table
Set tbl = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Table1").Table

tbl.Cell(r, c).Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = _
    tbl.Cell(r, c).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text
```

Is there some definitive guide on when I should use `TextFrame` vs when I should use `TextFrame2`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to Jon Peltier here: http://peltiertech.com/programming-excel-2007-2010-autoshapes-with-vba/

"The TextFrame2 member was added in Excel 2007 and gives better control over the formatting of the text. Because it is not backward compatible, I would recommend using the TextFrame object"

I'm guessing a similar situation applies in PPT.

Comment: Agreed, use the TextFrame object unless you need to do some of the wacky stuff that's only available via TextFrame2 (e.g. you want to set a particular underline style).

Comment: Of course, since my earlier tutorial, more people have upgraded from 2003 and earlier to 2007 and later, so my advice against using TextFrame2 is less relevant.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, `TextFrame` doesn't contain the property `LanguageID` in macOS, so you're forced to use `TextFrame2`. Be aware of that if you're working with that property in a cross-platform environment. I faced that problem [in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62230925/changing-language-in-powerpoint-through-vba-returns-compile-error-only-in-macos/).