# Changing language in PowerPoint through VBA returns compile error only in macOS

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have created a macro that changes the correction language of all the elements (text boxes, tables, groups...) in a PPT. I ended up with a code that works perfectly fine in Windows. However, when the macro runs in macOS it gives the error:

> Compile error: Method or data member not found

and highlights "*.LanguageID*" in the line:

```
Slides(i).Shapes(j).TextFrame.TextRange.LanguageID = iLanguageSelected
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `LanguageID` property was not included in the `TextFrame` object in PowerPoint after version 16.9.

The workaround is simple, just use `TextFrame2` instead of `TextFrame`:

```
Slides(i).Shapes(j).TextFrame2.TextRange.LanguageID = iLanguageSelected
```

`TextFrame2` also works with the same result in Windows so you can have one code for both OS.

Source: https://ourednik.info/maps/2011/04/11/change-the-language-to-englishus-on-all-slides-and-boxes-in-powerpoint-2007-or-2010/

Comment: What is the language ID for Persian please, if there is any?